# Установка AdRotator ver2.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

Тип проекта: Windows Store App для Windows 8/10(не Phone). Установил плагин AdRotator.
[Как в официальной инструкции написано](http://getadrotator.com/windows8/) - вставил в XAML-код:

```
<adRotator:AdRotatorControl x:Name="AdRotator"
            xmlns:adRotator="using:AdRotator" AdHeight="90" AdWidth="728"
            LocalSettingsLocation="defaultAdSettings.xml" AutoStartAds="True"/>
```

Ошибок компилятор не сообщает. Ок, запускаю - рекламы нет. Не понятно почему.
Хорошо, далее открыл локальный файл настроек "defaultAdSettings.xml" и подправил язык:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CultureDescriptors CultureName="en-US">
    <AdDuplex AppId="test_id" Probability="50" AdOrder="1"/>
    <PubCenter AppId="test_client" SecondaryId="Image480_80" Probability="50" />
  </CultureDescriptors>
</AdSettings>
```

Сейчас у меня в системе en-US. Но это без разницы - какие языки я бы ни писал все равно не работает.
Также, если менять значение параметра Probability и AppId - ничего не происходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить этот плагин чтобы работало правильно. Тысячу форумов прочитал - результат только такой - ошибок не пишет и ничего не отображает.

Comment: Вопрос актуален. Никто так и не знает в чем причина, что реклама не отображается? Как правильно настроить?